# Explicar código para separar string por 2 caracteres en una matriz bidimensional

Tags: java, array, string, split

¿Me podéis ayudar a entender qué es lo que se lleva a cabo en el bucle for? O sea, sé que este método devuelve una matriz, pero no llego a ver el momento en el que se rellena la segunda dimensión de la matriz.

El parámetro tendrá siempre un formato como

```
“Inditex;22.72;22.95 Telecinco;10.02;11.02”
```

(es decir, los nombres de cada Acción, su valor actual y su valor anterior, separando cada Acción por un espacio).

Devuelve una matriz de String en el que hay tantas filas como acciones en el array y cada fila tiene 3 columnas, la primera es el nombre, la segunda el valor y la tercera el valor anterior.

```
public String [][] partirString (String acc) {
     String [] [] res;
     //Primero partimos por el espacio
     String [] aux = acc.split(" ");
     //Con esto sabemos el número de filas de la matriz
     res = new String[aux.length][];
     //Ahora partiremos por el ;
     for (int ii=0; ii<aux.length;ii++){
          res[ii] = aux[ii].split(";");
     }
     return res;
}
```

Comment: Podrías agregar el `String` que recibe, para una mejor explicación

Comment: “Inditex;22.72;22.95 Telecinco;10.02;11.02”

Comment: ¿Podrías explicar brevemente lo que quieres hacer en general con el valor `acc` que le pasas a `partirString`? Lo digo porque leyendo el planteamiento me da la impresión de que podrías hacer las cosas de una forma más sencilla.

Comment: El codigo que he puesto es la solucion de un ejercicio y no entiendo muy bien como funciona

Comment: Un método partirString que recibe un String como parámetro. El parámetro
tendrá siempre un formato como “Inditex;22.72;22.95 Telecinco;10.02;11.02”(es decir, los nombres de cada Acción, su valor actual y su valor anterior, separando cada Acción por un espacio). Devuelve una matriz de String en el que hay tantas filas como acciones en el array y cada fila tiene 3 columnas, la primera es el nombre, la segunda el valor y la tercera el valor anterior. El método debe funcionar para cualquier número de acciones dentro del String.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Análisis rápido del código:

```
1  public String [][] partirString (String acc) {
2    String [] [] res;
3   
4    String [] aux = acc.split(" ");
5    //Con esto sabemos el número de filas de la matriz
6    res = new String[aux.length][];
7    //Ahora partiremos por el ;
8    for (int ii=0; ii<aux.length;ii++){
9      res[ii] = aux[ii].split(";");
10   }
11   return res;
12 }
```

Asumamos que ejecutamos `partirString(“Inditex;22.72;22.95 Telecinco;10.02;11.02”);`

En la línea 4 divide el String acc en partes, usando el espacio como divisor, por lo que aux valdría lo siguiente:

```
{ "Inditex;22.72;22.95", "Telecinco;10.02;11.02" }
```

La línea 6 crea un array de arrays del tamaño de `acc`, que en este caso sería 2:

```
aux= { null, null }
```

El bucle desde la línea 8 recorre `acc` y cada String lo vuelve a dividir en un array de Strings, usando ";" como separador. Cada array lo guarda en  `res[ii]`, con lo que el resultado final es algo como

```
{
  {"Inditex", "22.72","22.95"},
  {"Telecinco", "10.02","11.02"}
}
```

Comment: O sea, que el resultado final ya está prácticamente aquí, en la línea 4: `String [] aux = acc.split(" ");` Por eso [decía esto en mi comentario](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/131425/uso-split-clase-string-java#comment245072_131425).

Comment: Claro pero como pedia que tenia que haber tantas filas como acciones se vuelve a separar entiendo, gracias y un saludo a todos